# How to add the name before the array in the array object itself in a JSON response?

Tags: java, json

I am consuming an external web service and receiving a JSON response. In this response, there is an object "entities" containing multiple arrays in it, with a name before each array.

I want to add the name before the array in the array object itself.

For example this is the original response:

```
{

    "entities": {
        "entity": [
            {
                "confidence": 1,
                "value": "user",
                "type": "value"
            },
            {
                "confidence": 1,
                "value": "insurance form",
                "type": "value"
            }
        ],
        "ui_page_step": [
            {
                "confidence": 1,
                "value": "step 1",
                "type": "value"
            }
        ],
        "userrole_ano": [
            {
                "confidence": 0.96535832252792,
                "value": "anonymous user"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to convert it to:

```
{
  "entities": {
    "entity": [
      {
        "name": "entity",
        "confidence": 1,
        "value": "user",
        "type": "value"
      },
      {
        "name": "entity",
        "confidence": 1,
        "value": "insurance form",
        "type": "value"
      }
    ],
    "ui_page_step": [
      {
        "name": "ui_page_step",
        "confidence": 1,
        "value": "step 1",
        "type": "value"
      }
    ],
    "userrole_ano": [
      {
        "name": "userrole_ano",
        "confidence": 0.96535832252792,
        "value": "anonymous user"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I convert the original response to the desired one in Java?

Comment: show some attempt you have done so far

Comment: Why you want to edit JSON like this? Any specific reason?

Comment: Which library do you use to deserialize/serialize JSON?

Comment: The third party app needs it that way as response.
I have no code, library yet chosen, since I dont know where to begin.

Comment: Use JSONParser(). Parse it,  and add your "name" through an iterator at "entities". https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parse-json-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a (one of several possible) solutions:

1. It uses [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library to parse the Json into a java `Map` that is (relatively) easier to navigate and modify than JSONObject.
2. the method `putCollectionNamesInsideEntries()` assumes one root `"entities"` entry that has several collections as values. it iterates over all of them, adding `"name"` entry with name of collection.
3. the map is serialized back to Json (and sent to `System.out`)

   ```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.nio.file.*;
   import java.util.*;

   import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

   public class JacksonTest
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("C:/temp/test.json"))) {
               ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
               // deserialize json into map
               Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>)mapper.readValue(is, Map.class);
               putCollectionNamesInsideEntries(map);
               // serialize map into json
               mapper.writeValue(System.out, map);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       private static void putCollectionNamesInsideEntries(Map<String, Object> map) {
           // get root "entities" entry
           Map<String, Object> entitiesMap = (Map<String, Object>)map.get("entities");
           for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entitiesEntry : entitiesMap.entrySet()) {
               // iterate over collection entries
               if (entitiesEntry.getValue() instanceof Collection) {
                   Collection coll = (Collection)entitiesEntry.getValue();
                   // iterate over entries in collection
                   for (Object collEntry : coll) {
                       if (collEntry instanceof Map) {
                           // add "name" with ame of collection (key entry under "entries")
                           ((Map<String, Object>)collEntry).put("name", entitiesEntry.getKey());
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Why would you go around with all these callings? ObjectMapper has really cool write methods for writing directly within JsonNode->ArrayNode whatever we like.

Comment: @MS90, I'll be glad if you show how easy it is to work with JsonMode and ArrayNode. I found it hard and unintuitive to work with this api